# Modify wordpress pages widget and turn it into a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I would like to make a plug-in that adds a widget in wordpress.

I would like the widget to be based on the current pages widget but add the ability to select either include OR exclude by drop down or checkbox then list pages by ID.

Following [this](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/04/09/modify-the-wordpress-pages-widget-to-include-pages-instead-of-exclude-pages) guide I was able to change the exclude to include by hacking the core file located in wp-includes/default_widgets.php.

Here is the original default_widgets.php:

http://pastebin.com/Rg2vTMmK

How do I make the changes and turn it into a plugin?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-reloaded/